# Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) and Route 53 in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I'm new to AWS and just started learning it.

`Load Balancing` is something that is common which we will use for load distribution when we have multiple servers.

Here, when I learnt about `Route 53` in AWS, it sounds similar to load balancing. Although we can do more with Route53 (like `A` , `CNAME` , `ALIAS` etc.,). My doubt is, can we use `weighted` or `latency` or `failover` based routing policy instead of load balancer? Is it possible to reduce the cost incurred for `ELB` if we are using Route53? How effective will it be and what are the drawbacks?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Both Route53 and ELB are used to distribute the network traffic. These AWS services appear similar but there are minor differences between them.

1. ELB distributes traffic among Multiple Availability Zone but not to multiple Regions. Route53 can distribute traffic among multiple Regions. In short, ELBs are intended to load balance across EC2 instances in a single region whereas DNS load-balancing (Route53) is intended to help balance traffic across regions.
2. Both Route53 and ELB perform health check and route traffic to only healthy resources. Route53 weighted routing has health checks and removes unhealthy targets from its list. **However, DNS is cached so unhealthy targets will still be in the visitors cache for some time.** On the other hand, ELB is not cached and will remove unhealthy targets from the target group immediately.

Use both Route53 and ELB: Route53 provides integration with ELB. You can use both Route53 and ELB in your AWS infrastructure. If you have AWS resources in multiple regions, you can use Route53 to balance the load among those regions. Inside the region, you can use ELB to load balance among the instances running in various Availability Zones.

Comment: Please address the issue of cost too?  Which one is cheaper - ELB or Route53? Many Thanks.

Comment: @Banoona R53 will always be cheaper. ELBs come at 20USD per month, R53 will be at 0.60USD per month (depending on the region/traffic ofc)

Answer (score 10):

In addition to what @thomasVdBerge has answered (which is well explained), I would like to add that ELB has an advantage when it comes to routing rules such as routing based on path and query. Also, it has a possibility to send a fixed response for specific rules.