# Difference between ELB & Route 53 health checks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

Do you still need R53 health checks if you have activated ELB health checks and your only traffic is directed to ELB? What do R53 and ELB health checks do separately?

edit: punctuation

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57321793/elastic-load-balancer-elb-and-route-53-in-aws

Comment: "However, DNS is cached so unhealthy targets will still be in the visitors cache for some time. On the other hand, ELB is not cached and will remove unhealthy targets from the target group immediately."
Does this mean that ELB health checks are more powerful? If we have ELB health checks, do we still need R53 health checks? Thanks for the link, very helpful! :)